# Error when trying to crawl external site with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to crawl an external job posting board and grab the data for each job posting. Right now I'm just trying to collect the data for the first job posting in the list of job posting. I cant seem to get it to stop erroring on me saying:

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null`

I havent used puppeteer much so i may just have a simple syntax issue im not seeing.The address on the data I'm trying to crawl: [Canvas Job Postings](https://recruiting2.ultipro.com/PUB1004PSCU/JobBoard/d433f5c3-37c8-4bcf-a3af-248a707c7d31/?q=&o=postedDateDesc)

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();


    const oportunities = [];
    const opportunity = {
        title: '',
        desc: '',
        category: '',
        reqName: '',
        hours: '',
        postingDate: '',
        address: ''
    };
  await page.goto('https://recruiting2.ultipro.com/PUB1004PSCU/JobBoard/d433f5c3-37c8-4bcf-a3af-248a707c7d31/?q=&o=postedDateDesc');

  const title = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return document.querySelector('.opportunity .row .col-lg-20 h3 a').textContent
  });

  opportunity.title = title;

  console.log(opportunity);

  browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

The expression `document.querySelector('.opportunity .row .col-lg-20 h3 a')` returns `null`, meaning that the selector does not find any elements.

Most likely, this is the case, because although the `load` event has been triggered, the page is not done yet building.

**Solution**

The simplest way to solve this, is to wait for the element to appear, before continuing your script. You can use [`page.waitForSelector`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.19.0/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options) for this like this:

```js
await page.goto(/* ... */);

await page.waitForSelector('.opportunity .row .col-lg-20 h3 a');

// continue with the remaining script...
```